# Excel vba Find cell address of one of list of values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of string values. One of those string values exists in my data range. I want to get the cell address of where that string exists without doing a loop.

Microsoft [documentation indicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) **.Find (what, LookIn...**
that *what* is

> The data to search for. Can be a string or any Microsoft Excel data type.

So I tried to use an ArrayList as follows since the arraylist is helpful in other parts of the implementation.

```
Dim staSearchList As Object
Set staSearchList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
staSearchList.Add "Sta Pending Secs"
staSearchList.Add "Adjusted Sta Wait Secs"
staSearchList.Add "STATION WAIT SECONDS"

With Worksheets(transSheet.Name).Range(titleRangeStr)
    'Set staWait = .Find(staSearchList, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set staWait = .Find(staSearchList, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not staWait Is Nothing Then
        adjCol = staWait.Column
    Else
        iConfirmMsg = MsgBox("Station Wait Column not found. Exiting. ", vbInformation)
        GoTo exitCreateBrackets
    End If
End With
```

The error message I'm getting is Run-time error

> Missing parameter does not have default value

Is it possible to use an arraylist with the .Find method? Is there another way to search for multiple values across a range of cells and get the cell address where one of those values exist, without using a loop? Seems to me that Excel is so range oriented I shouldn't need a loop. ;-)

To clarify and answer the questions, this is searching multiple rows of headers. And only one of the values will be present, but there is the possibility that none are present. I can definitely implement with a loop, I was curious if there was a better way, something built into Excel/vba.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a .Net Type, not an Excel data type - they mean "type" like `String`, `Date`, `Long`, `Variant`, etc  If you don't want loops in your main code then you can abstract that out into a function.  Non-loop solutions tend to be a bit obscure (such as `Evaluate`'ing an array function string for example)

Comment: Will it always be the case that 1 and only 1 of the searched for strings will be found?  Or could it find multiple occurrences (like it finds 2 out of 3)?  If it can find multiple occurrences, what result do you want?

Comment: Are you searching a single row for the headers?

Comment: Regardless of what you use, Dictionary, Array, List. You want to do a `For Each item in Array` loop to look for all values in the array. There may be other ways, but this would be the simplest and easier.